# Scheduling the parallel prefix algorithm

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, parallel-processing

I want to implement the parallel prefix algorithm (with POSIX threads or OpenMP). I have pseudocode for the parallel algorithm, but I don't know how to implement it.

```
parallelPrefix(array)
    if array.length = 1
        result[1] = array[1]
        return result[]
    for 1 <= i <= floor(n / 2) pardo
        temp[i] = array[2 * i - 1] + array[2 * i]
    prefixSums[] = parallelPrefix(temp[])
    for 1 <= i <= n pardo
        if i is even result[i] = prefixSums[i / 2]
        if i = 1     result[i] = array[1]
        if i is odd  result[i] = prefixSums[(i - 1) / 2] + temp[i]
     return result[]
```

(This algorithm is basically given to us in the lecture notes, I didn't come up with it myself and actually I want to use a similar algorithm which notation is slightly less elegant, but which works in-place)

My problem is that I am not sure how to schedule this. The 'pardo' notation means that the loop is done in parallel, but I'm not sure how to map this to a finite number of processors. I can, of course, create a thread for every instance of the loop, but this seems like an overkill (I imagine the extra overhead for starting a new thread would be much bigger than the gain from the parallelism).

Another, slightly better, option would be dividing the work in the parallel loop between the processors. This way we would use less threads, but still have to start a bunch of threads for every parallel for-loop.

Both options seem far from ideal, so I must be missing something. I don't know what the preferred solution is and I would love to hear some suggestions.

edit: I realize that using synchronization primitives would be another option. But this would get kind of complicated (I imagine), and I would still need some kind of policy to map the work to the processors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Parallelization potential of the algorithm

The algorithm you present is quite challenging to parallelize: Lots and lots of new `for` loop instances with very little to do in every iteration. I had to use a huge array in order to achieve any speed-up at all, so huge that I almost ran out of memory (~13 GB occupied by the process). But you mentioned that you want to implement a different, in-place algorithm. That will reduce the memory footprint dramatically and you will be able to execute the algorithm for problems big enough to see a significant speed-up.

### Errors

I think, your algorithm has some errors. Firstly, `n` is never defined. I assume, it refers to `array.length`, in order for the algorithm to make sense. Secondly, the line

```
if i is odd  result[i] = prefixSums[(i - 1) / 2] + temp[i]
```

should be

```
if i is odd  result[i] = prefixSums[(i - 1) / 2] + array[i]
```

### OpenMP

#### Thread creation

In OpenMP you don't have to take care of the thread creation and scheduling yourself, so your parallel loop

```
for 1 <= i <= n pardo
```

can simply be written as

```
int i;
#pragma omp parallel for shared(i)
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    /* loop body */
}
```

in C or

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    // loop body
}
```

in C++ or

```
!$omp parallel do private(i)
do i=1,n
    ! loop body
end do
!$omp end parallel do
```

in Fortran (you haven't specified the programming language you want to use). Transforming the other parallel loop works the same way.

This will create as many threads as OpenMP deems adequate, normally the number of processors that your operating system sees (that includes complete processors, cores in multi-core processors and virtual HyperThreading cores). However, that can be overridden by different means.

#### Choosing a schedule

The iterations will be distributed to the threads by OpenMP. By default, this happens using a static schedule that divides the full loop range into chunks for every thread. If your iterations are very unbalanced in computational effort and you have too few iterations to even that out, you can ask for a dynamic schedule using the `schedule(dynamic)` clause in the OpenMP directive. But I don't see a need for that in your case.

#### Overhead

So you won't have one thread per iteration, as you mentioned, but just as many threads as make sense on the particular system. Even in that case, however, there might be some overhead for creating and destroying the threads, and that overhead might eat up what you gain from the parallelization, especially for short/cheap loops.

In your example that would be the case for a small `n`. Assuming that by `n` you mean `array.length` (otherwise your algorithm wouldn't make sense), this can be the case when you get close to the base case in your recursion.

I wouldn't worry too much about this because in your algorithm there aren't too many of those cases. In other types of recursive algorithms on arrays, e.g. Divide & Conquer algorithms, the base case is executed for every element of the original array ([see the last line in this diagram](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cburch/pgss99/lecture/0721tree.gif)). Unlike those algorithms, your recursion is linear and therefore you will have few of those critical executions.

Also, some OpenMP implementations decide to keep a bunch of threads alive, just in case, and use them, when they are needed. In this case, you don't have to worry at all about the overhead.

In case you decide the overhead matters and your OpenMP implementation doesn't keep the threads alive itself, you have 2 options:

**Deactivate threads for small `n`**

You can deactivate parallel execution for those easy executions by using the `num_threads` directive to override the number of threads in the case of having few iterations, e.g.

```
procs = n > 100000 ? omp_get_num_procs() : 1;
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(procs)
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    /* loop body */
}
```

Note that you need to include `omp.h` in order to access `omp_get_num_procs()`. A full C++ example:

```
std::vector<int> parallelPrefix_withNumThreads(const std::vector<int> &array) {
    int n = array.size();
    int procs = n > 100 ? omp_get_num_procs() : 1;
    std::vector<int> result(n);
    if (n == 1) {
        result[0] = array[0];
        return result;
    }
    std::vector<int> temp(n / 2);
    #pragma omp parallel for shared(temp, array) num_threads(procs)
    for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
        temp[i] = array[2 * i] + array[2 * i + 1];
    }
    std::vector<int> prefixSums = parallelPrefix_withNumThreads(temp);
    #pragma omp parallel for shared(temp, array) num_threads(procs)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            result[i] = prefixSums[i / 2];
        } else if (i == 0) {
            result[i] = array[0];
        } else if (i % 2 == 0) {
            result[i] = prefixSums[i / 2 - 1] + array[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

By setting the number of threads to 1 for the easy cases, you tell OpenMP not to create any additional threads in those cases. All work will be executed in the (already existing) master thread. This removes almost all of the overhead for those cases.

Which limit you have to set and if this improves the performance at all, depends heavily on your machine and your OpenMP implementation. The GCC 4.9.2 that I was using to test the performance reuses its OpenMP threads anyway. In this setup, I couldn't observe any improvement at all with this trick. But this might be different for other OpenMP implementations.

**Keep threads alive**

If your initial `n` is very small and you still want to try to get some speed-up out of the parallelization, you can force OpenMP to keep your threads alive between the parallel sections. This can be done by having one `omp parallel` section that contains all the `omp for` loop executions.

However, whether all this is worth the effort, depends heavily on the OpenMP implementation you use. Again, the GCC 4.9.2 that I was using to test the performance reuses its OpenMP threads. In this setup, pulling the `omp parallel` directive out wasn't necessary and therefore didn't help at all, it even reduced the performance a little. But this might be different for other OpenMP implementations.

Example code in C++:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> parallelPrefix_outsideParallel(const std::vector<int> &array) {
    int n = array.size();
    std::vector<int> result(n);
    if (n == 1) {
        result[0] = array[0];
        return result;
    }
    std::vector<int> temp(n / 2);
    std::vector<int> prefixSums;
    #pragma omp parallel shared(array, result, prefixSums) firstprivate(n)
    {
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
            temp[i] = array[2 * i] + array[2 * i + 1];
        }
        #pragma omp single
        {
            prefixSums = parallelPrefix_outsideParallel(temp);
        }
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 1) {
                result[i] = prefixSums[i / 2];
            } else if (i == 0) {
                result[i] = array[0];
            } else if (i % 2 == 0) {
                result[i] = prefixSums[i / 2 - 1] + array[i];
            }
        }
    } // end parallel
    return result;
}
```

The outside `omp parallel` directive now contains both `for` loops as well as the recursive call. So all `omp for` directives, both in the current function instance and in all recursive instances of the function will use the threads created by this single `omp parallel` directive.

Make sure that [`OMP_NESTED` is set to `FALSE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5270/aewbc/index.html), otherwise every recursive call will span a new set of threads, littering your system with threads.

The `omp single` directive makes sure that only one thread of the pool makes the recursive call.

Note that there are implicit barrier synchronizations at the end of both `omp for` blocks and at the end of the `omp single` blocks. Without them, the implementation would have race conditions.

### POSIX

The principal scheduling ideas still apply, if you want to use POSIX threads. However, here it is your own responsibility to manage the thread's lifecycle. You have to create a number of threads and then assign them their work.

If you have the choice, don't go there and use OpenMP instead. Especially reusing of threads for different `for` loop instances, like it is required for this particular problem (see OpenMP section), can be very challenging to implement.

#### Static schedule

Using a static schedule, the calculation of the loop range of every thread can look like this (assuming the `numThreads` is the number of threads you created, and `threadId` is a number from 0 to `numThreads-1` that identifies every thread):

```
int getStartIndex(int threadId, int numThreads, int n) {
    return 1 + threadId * n / numThreads + min(threadId, n % numThreads);
}

int startIndex = getStartIndex(threadId, numThreads, n);
int nextThreadStartIndex = getStartIndex(threadId + 1, numThreads, n);

for (int i = startIndex; i < nextThreadStartIndex; i++) {
    // loop body
}
```

This will execute the whole loop from index 1 to `n`, divided into chunks for every thread. The distribution will be as even as possible, `n / numThreads` iterations for each thread. If it's not possible to make it completely even, the first `n % numThreads` threads will each receive 1 iteration more than the rest (that's what the `min(threadId, n % numThreads)` expression is for).

#### Dynamic schedule

A dynamic schedule can be implemented by maintaining a queue (e.g. implemented as a list) of iterations managed by a central instance. Every thread has a `while` loop that asks for new iterations (or better for efficiency: small blocks of iterations) and executes them. When the central queue is empty, all threads except the master thread terminate and the master thread waits for all other threads that might still be executing an iteration, (barrier synchronization) before going on with the sequential part of the code.

The management of the central queue requires some thread synchronization codes in order to avoid race conditions and possible corruption of your queue.

However, given that your iterations are quite uniform in computational cost, I would avoid the effort of a dynamic schedule altogether.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get a tiny bit of speedup using 4 threads and a large problem instance. The work of the parallel algorithm is of the same order, but there is appearently a large overhead. In the end, I wrote the algorithm with the for loop on the outside, effectively keeping the threads alive.